# What are the requirements for EF6 eager loading to work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Mine appears to be set up correctly, but the child object is coming back null.  Even the SQL output shows the join (and yes, there are keys set up to join):

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[IsVesselizable] AS [IsVesselizable], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
[Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId], 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1]
FROM  [dbo].[MenuItems] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MenuItemCategories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CategoryId] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

Here's the API function:

```
    // GET: api/MenuItems
    public IQueryable<MenuItem> GetMenuItems()
    {
        return db.MenuItems.Include(m => m.Category);
    }
```

and some of the MenuItem class:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public MenuItemCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

EF seems like it should make everything so easy, but obviously I've missed something here.  I don't need to make that last line like this, do I?

```
public MenuItemCategory MenuItemCategory { get; set; }
```

Comment: is the value in the database? have you tried executing a similar SQL on your database and see the resultset?

Comment: write down your MenuItemCategory class and the Fluent API configuration

Comment: I think `return db.MenuItems.Include(m => m.Category).ToList()` thjis will get value if you have in the database

Comment: @DevilSuichiro good idea, and everything is coming back as expected in the realm of SQL.  Turns out, the method was totally working while I was actually seeing the results of getting a specific MenuItem instead of the whole collection.  But how do I modify this line in GetMenuItem(id) to get the related entity?  {MenuItem menuItem = await db.MenuItems.FindAsync(id);}

Comment: "seeing the results of getting a specific MenuItem instead of the whole collection" I don't understand this part. What exactly is wrong now, if the method was working? related to what, doesn't include do the same?

Comment: I didn't think the method was working because I was thinking the "GetAll" function was firing when it was actually the "GetBy(id)" that was bringing back the results I was seeing.  Fortunately I ran into the answer on how to modify that Get(Id) to also include the child object: `           MenuItem menuItem = await db.MenuItems
                .Include(m => m.Category)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);`